# Infinite stochastic matrices and associated bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, markov-chains

Consider a continuous-time Markov chain $X_t$ on $\mathbb{N}$ with transition matrix function $P(t) = (p_{ij}(t))$ for $t \geq 0$ where $p_{ij}(t) := P(X_t = j \mid X_0 = i)$.

In the literature, I met the following two different directions for the analysis of $P(t)$:

1. Componentwise analysis: Assume that each component $p_{ij}(t)$ is continuous in $t \geq 0$. Then the limits $q_{ij} := \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} (p_{ij}(h) - p_{ij}(0))$ exist in $[-\infty, \infty)$ and satisfy $0 \leq q_{ij} < \infty$ for $i \neq j$ and $-\infty \leq q_{ii} \leq -\sum_j q_{ij} \leq 0$.
   Set $Q := (q_{ij})$ as the infinite matrix with components in $[-\infty, \infty)$. $Q$ is called the "generator matrix" of $P(t)$. $Q$ is a matrix with components in $\mathbb{R}$ iff all $q_{ii}$ are finite.
2. Analysis of $P(t)$ as a semigroup of bounded linear operators on $\ell^\infty$:
   For each $t \geq 0$ we can consider $P(t)$ as a bounded operator in $B(\ell^\infty)$ defined by $(P(t)x)_i := \sum_j p_{ij}(t) x_j$ for $x \in \ell^\infty$. We can equip $B(\ell^\infty)$ with the strong operator topology and assume that $P : [0, \infty) \to B(\ell^\infty)$ is continuous, in which case $P(t)$ is called a $C_0$-semigroup (or strongly continuous semigroup). Then $P(t)$ has generator $Q$ which is a possibly unbounded operator on $\ell^\infty$. $Q$ is a bounded operator iff $P(t)$ is uniformly continuous, i.e. a continuous map $P : [0, \infty) \to B(\ell^\infty)$ where now $B(\ell^\infty)$ carries the operator norm topology.

Clearly, there are connections between these two types of analysis:

- the generator matrix $Q$ in 1. corresponds to the possibly unbounded generator $Q$ in 2.
- the generator matrix $Q$ has uniformly bounded components ($\sup_i |q_{ii}| < \infty$) iff the generator $Q$ is bounded.

The componentwise analysis has the advantage that one does not have to introduce a seemingly auxiliary and artifical space $X$ (here $X = \ell^\infty)$ which allows to consider $P(t)$ as a bounded linear operator on $B(X)$. On the other hand, 2. seems to be quite flexible and also allows to use tools from Functional Analysis such as spectral analysis that are not easily available for the componentwise analysis in 1. (since dealing with infinite matrices can be quite cumbersome).

There are also differences between 1. and 2. and one has to be aware of them. Example: assume for simplicity that the generator $Q$ is bounded or equivalently that $\sup_i |q_{ii}| < \infty$. Then it is known that $P(t)$ as a matrix converges componentwise to some matrix $P_\infty$ as $t \to \infty$. However, $P(t) = \exp(Qt)$ as a bounded operator on $B(\ell^\infty)$ equipped with the norm topology does not need to converge - it only converges wrt the strong operator topology; the norm topology is too strong.

**Questions:**

1. What is so special about the space $\ell^\infty$ that this is chosen so often in the broad literature on Markov chains? One can also imagine other locally convex sequence spaces $X$ on which $P(t)$ acts as a bounded linear operator in the same way as on $\ell^\infty$. (Note also that related to 2. one can also let $P(t)$ act on $\ell^1$ from the left (i.e. as a transformation of measures) which is some kind of adjoint to the action of $P(t)$ on $\ell^\infty$.)
2. For different $X$ one could imagine that the analysis (e.g. spectral analysis) of $P(t)$ or $Q$ with respect to $X$ is also different. Are there some connections between these types of analysis?
3. Having fixed $X$, we then have also a wide variety on the choice of "suitable" locally convex topologies on the space of continuous (or bounded) linear operators on $X$. Is there something known about locally convex topologies in between the operator norm topology and the strong operator topology and their correspondences to properties of the generator matrix $Q$?

Comment: In your component-wise analysis, how does the existence of $p’_{ij}(0)$ follow from the continuity of $p_{ij}(t)$?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 This is a standard result, see e.g. [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=CCvvCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Differentiability&f=false)